# Creating a simple directive with Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am having a very simple problem and I can't figure out why it's not working.

**reviewCtrl.html**

```
angular.module('liveAPP.review',['LiveAPP.factory'])
.controller('reviewCtrl', ['$scope','$http','dataFactory','$location',reviewCtrl])

.directive("datePicker", function() {
    return {
        restrict: "E",
        template: '<div>I want this to show up in my review view</div>'
  }      
})
```

**review.html**

```
<datePicker></datePicker>
```

My expectation of this code is to see "I want this to show up in my review view" in the view corresponding to this controller. The view is injected into the  `<div ng-view></div>` in my index.html. I have a very simple example here, but for some reason its not working how I would expect. Assume my routes are set up correctly. Anyone have any idea why this might be?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use

```
 <date-picker>
```

in your  html it will work.

Because Angular converts camelCasing to snake-casing, so your datePicker directive needs to be renamed to date-picker in html.

---

**Why to use CamelCasing:**

---

**[Normalization:](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive)**

Angular normalizes an element's tag and attribute name to determine which elements match which directives. We typically refer to directives by their case-sensitive [camelCase](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CamelCase) normalized name (e.g. ngModel). However, since HTML is case-insensitive, we refer to directives in the DOM by lower-case forms, typically using [dash-delimited](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Letter_case#Computers) attributes on DOM elements (e.g. ng-model).

The normalization process is as follows:

Strip x- and data- from the front of the element/attributes.
Convert the :, -, or _-delimited name to camelCase.

---

> See this example: http://jsfiddle.net/kevalbhatt18/khz8vxs4/1/

Comment: WHAT? That's crazy. So it gets split by a dash when there is a capital letter?

Comment: Also add `best practive` below to the answer ;)